# Is the Twitter client for Android using OAuth?

Tags: android, twitter, oauth

Since basic auth has been deprecated, is the official android twitter app using OAuth?
It still asks for my userid & password & I'm wondering how they are retrieving the oauth token ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like they could be using xAuth - http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth. It's an alternate method of authenticating via OAuth. xAuth access is restricted to approved applications, you can't use it unless Twitter says you can.

Comment: I wonder what their criteria is for allowing apps to use xAuth.

Comment: @Frankie Ribery: Not entirely sure. They do say "If your application is a desktop or mobile application and the standard web OAuth flow or PIN-code out-of-band flow is not right for you, send a detailed message to api@twitter.com to request xAuth privileges". Not sure which situations would make the normal flows "not right for you", though. Maybe email them and ask?

Answer (score 0):

Android client is using oAuth for twitter for example.
User must login to twitter at least once through your app and get a key.
It can be used several times and you dont need to get a key again.